# How to handle a integer value bigger than the max int(64) can store?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I was building a clicker typed game where you click a button to earn points.

The problem is after you reach a the ULONG_MAX value, c++ cant handle that big values anymore.

Any algorithms to use arrays to store and handle big values?
I have heard that you can do these types of stuff with arrays.

I tried to but i cant figure out any properly working algorithms.

Comment: Short of using a floating point precision variable or platform-specific type, you need to do it manually or use an external library.

Comment: ***Any algorithms to use arrays to store and handle big values?*** Yes there exist big integer libraries.

Comment: Egad how many points are you giving out such that you're overflowing a 64 bit int? :)

Comment: I agree, that seems a bit crazy.

Comment: I tried to explain my problem very simply, of course you can upgrade different stuff to get more points, but it didn't really relate to the question.